# Can't install curb gem in Linux Mint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, curb

I have a problem with installing curb. When I type in my console:

```
 sudo gem install curb
```

It returns me following error:

```
Fetching: curb-0.8.6.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing curb:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
checking for curl-config... no
checking for main() in -lcurl... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/bin/ruby1.9.1
    --with-curl-dir
    --without-curl-dir
    --with-curl-include
    --without-curl-include=${curl-dir}/include
    --with-curl-lib
    --without-curl-lib=${curl-dir}/lib
    --with-curllib
    --without-curllib
extconf.rb:23:in `<main>':   Can't find libcurl or curl/curl.h (RuntimeError)

  Try passing --with-curl-dir or --with-curl-lib and --with-curl-include
  options to extconf.


Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/curb-0.8.6 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/curb-0.8.6/ext/gem_make.out
```

I don't have any idea how to solve this problem. I was looking for some solution in Google but not find anything that will help me to solve this problem. Please help...

EDIT:

Here is mkmf.log file. Maybe it will be helpfull in debuging:

```
find_executable: checking for curl-config... -------------------- no

--------------------

have_library: checking for main() in -lcurl... -------------------- no

"gcc -o conftest -I/usr/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux -I/usr/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/usr/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2  -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing -fPIC conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/lib -L. -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -L/build/buildd/ruby1.9.1-1.9.3.484/debian/lib -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic     -lruby-1.9.1  -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: int main(int argc, char **argv)
4: {
5:   return 0;
6: }
/* end */

"gcc -o conftest -I/usr/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux -I/usr/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/usr/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2  -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing -fPIC conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/lib -L. -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -L/build/buildd/ruby1.9.1-1.9.3.484/debian/lib -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic     -lruby-1.9.1 -lcurl  -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
conftest.c: In function ‘t’:
conftest.c:4:53: error: ‘main’ undeclared (first use in this function)
 int t() { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))main; return 0; }
                                                     ^
conftest.c:4:53: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
conftest.c:4:28: warning: variable ‘p’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
 int t() { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))main; return 0; }
                            ^
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: /*top*/
 4: int t() { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))main; return 0; }
 5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 6: {
 7:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 8:     printf("%p", &t);
 9:   }
10: 
11:   return 0;
12: }
/* end */

"gcc -o conftest -I/usr/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux -I/usr/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/usr/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2  -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing -fPIC conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/lib -L. -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -L/build/buildd/ruby1.9.1-1.9.3.484/debian/lib -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic     -lruby-1.9.1 -lcurl  -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
conftest.c: In function ‘t’:
conftest.c:4:1: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘main’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
 int t() { main(); return 0; }
 ^
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcurl
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: /*top*/
 4: int t() { main(); return 0; }
 5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 6: {
 7:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 8:     printf("%p", &t);
 9:   }
10: 
11:   return 0;
12: }
/* end */

--------------------
```

Comment: `curb` needs the package `libcurl-dev`. Try to install this package and retry to install `curb`

Comment: @Robin post the answer i wanna upvote it is right direction. BTW this very good explain in README for this gem.

Comment: @Зелёный: Only the right direction. I didn't know the exact names of the package on mint :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are on Ubuntu do this before proceeding:

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl3 libcurl3-gnutls libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

Alternatively for other OS install, download package from here after selecting your OS:

http://curl.haxx.se/dlwiz/?type=devel

Comment: glad to to of help :)

Answer (score 2):

Your Mint installation is probably missing the curl dev libraries.

Try this on the command line:

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

Use command from previous answer

`sudo apt-get install libcurl3 libcurl3-gnutls libcurl4-openssl-dev`

Sometimes Mint can't install `libcurl4-openssl-dev` because of next error.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libldap2-dev : Depends: libldap-2.4-2 (= 2.4.31-1+nmu2ubuntu8.2) but 2.4.31-1+nmu2ubuntu8.3 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

In my case I've resolved it with next command:

`sudo aptitude install libldap2-dev`

At first it suggested to do nothing, I've selected No, then it suggested to downgrade my current install to proper version. I've selected Yes. Then I was able to install `libcurl4-openssl-dev` as usual